# need to find child element from python list

Tags: python, list, iterator, match

i have a python list as below

```
[(u'1', u'0'), (u'2', u'1'), (u'3', u'2'), (u'4', u'3'), (u'5', u'4'), (u'6', u'4'), (u'7', u'4'), (u'8', u'4'), (u'9', u'4'), (u'10', u'4'), (u'11', u'4'), (u'11.5', u'2'), (u'12', u'11.5'), (u'13', u'11.5'), (u'14', u'11.5'), (u'15', u'11.5'), (u'16', u'11.5'), (u'17', u'11.5'), (u'18', u'11.5'), (u'19', u'11.5'), (u'20', u'11.5'), (u'21', u'11.5'), (u'22', u'11.5'), (u'23', u'11.5'), (u'24', u'11.5'), (u'25', u'11.5'), (u'26', u'11.5'), (u'27', u'11.5'), (u'28', u'11.5'), (u'30', u'11.5'), (u'29', u'11.5')]
```

here each tuple's 1st place is its own id while 2nd position is its parent id.

i want to get all child of specific id. 
Example, if i want to get the list of all ownids who are child(or child of child... to n depth) of own id "3".
 so answer list will be `[u'4', u'5', u'6', u'7', u'8', u'9', u'10', u'11']`

any way to do this??

Comment: You can do this with a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm. However, I would suggest you build a more efficient representation of your tree, since this query will take O(n²) time when run on this adjacency list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `networkx` library...

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edges_from( (y,x) for x,y in your_list )
print list(nx.dfs_postorder_nodes(g, '3'))
[u'11', u'10', u'5', u'7', u'6', u'9', u'8', u'4', '3']
```

Comment: It is nice to see that someone thought to use a graph library for this

Answer (score 2):

If you have no defined number of levels…

With your list `li`:

```
d = {}
for o, p in li:
    d.setdefault(p, []).append(o)
todo = d[u'3'][:]
descendants = []
while todo:
    node = todo.pop(0)
    todo.extend(d.get(node, []))
    descendants.append(node)
```

`descendants` contains the sought list.

Comment: what if max level is not defined!!!!! we don't know... the maximum value of depth...then???

Comment: @NamitKewat: you said you wanted the descendants up to level *n*, so you get code that works up to level *n*. Of course, you can always set *n* to your number of nodes.

Comment: @eumiro: +1 for an interesting take on BFS.

Comment: @NamitKewat - ok, if you want all descendants, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the relation doesn't change often, one solution is to build the transitive closure, thus:

```py
def tclose(data):
    data = set(data)
    while True:
        new = set( (a, d)
                   for (a, b) in data
                   for (c, d) in data
                   if b == c ) - data
        if not new:
            return data
        data.update(new)

data = tclose([(u'1', u'0'), …])
```

Then you can locate descendants, thus:

```
descendants = set( d for (d, a) in data if a == '3' )
```

If you want to limit the search to a fixed depth, you can replace `while True` with `for _ in range(n - 1)`. If `n` varies, you'll need a different solution.

Note that this solution focuses on simplicity. It isn't the fastest possible algorithm, and might need rehab if you give it a large input set.

Comment: Where is the `n` to which level to go?

Comment: @eumiro: I didn't think *n* was a specific number, more like a euphemism for arbitrary depth.

Comment: I thought that too. Then the things got complicated…

Comment: here level of depth is not defined. We have to find out all children until each child has no child.

Comment: @NamitKewat: Just in case, I've amended my answer to cover a specific value of `n`. But I think, based on your comment here, that the answer is correct as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

mylist = [(u'1', u'0'), (u'2', u'1'), (u'3', u'2'), (u'4', u'3'), (u'5', u'4'), (u'6', u'4'), (u'7', u'4'), (u'8', u'4'), (u'9', u'4'), (u'10', u'4'), (u'11', u'4'), (u'11.5', u'2'), (u'12', u'11.5'), (u'13', u'11.5'), (u'14', u'11.5'), (u'15', u'11.5'), (u'16', u'11.5'), (u'17', u'11.5'), (u'18', u'11.5'), (u'19', u'11.5'), (u'20', u'11.5'), (u'21', u'11.5'), (u'22', u'11.5'), (u'23', u'11.5'), (u'24', u'11.5'), (u'25', u'11.5'), (u'26', u'11.5'), (u'27', u'11.5'), (u'28', u'11.5'), (u'30', u'11.5'), (u'29', u'11.5')]

def make_tree(lst):
    """
    Accepts a list of (item, parent)
    Returns a dict of parent:[children]
    """
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for child,parent in lst:
        res[parent].append(child)
    return res

def find_children(tree, root, max_depth=-1):
    """
    Accepts a dict of parent:[children]
    Returns a recursive list of (child, [children_of_child]) of root to the given maximum depth
      (if max_depth is negative, recursion is not limited)
    """
    if max_depth and (root in tree):
        return [(child, find_children(tree, child, max_depth-1)) for child in tree[root]]
    else:
        return []

def flatten(ans):
    """
    Accepts a recursive list
    Returns a flat list of nodes
    """
    res = []
    for parent,children in ans:
        res.append(parent)
        res.extend(flatten(children))
    return res

print flatten(find_children(build_tree(mylist), u'3', 4))
```

results in

```
[u'4', u'5', u'6', u'7', u'8', u'9', u'10', u'11']
```